# Appropriate test for betweenness centrality by group

Tags: r, hypothesis-testing, categorical-data, social-network

I have a data set looking like this (in R):

```
> head(data)

         Score Group
1 3.559288e-04     a
2 7.182034e-06     b
3 1.325869e-04     d
4 3.216735e-04     a
5 0.000000e+00     e
6 2.132424e-02     f
...
```

and I need to test whether there is a relationship between belonging to a particular group (a, b, c, etc.) and obtaining a higher score.

This is the distribution of scores (which is normalized, hence all possible values fall between 0 and 1):

[image]

What's the appropriate test for this kind of problem?

Comment: Do you want to compare on *both* `Var2` & `Var1` together, or do you want to stratify on `Var1` & run 2 parallel tests on `Var2`? What kind of data are `Score`? Ie, are they normal?

Comment: Indeed, I want to stratify on Var1 and run 2 parallel tests on Var2. I'm checking right now the distribution of Score...

Comment: I added an histogram, hope this clarifies it a bit...

Comment: What are the `Score`s? Are they counts of something or continuous? Do you have actual $0$ values (& if not, is that theoretically possible)?

Comment: Based on the distribution of Score and the obvious extreme values pushing down the small values onto the 0 (or close to it) bucket, you will want to consider a multiple group, nonparametric comparison test.

Comment: @gung, the data is a betweenness centrality score in a network (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Betweenness_centrality). The values go from 0 on... I could normalize it though... Will try to do this now...

Comment: Thanks @DJohnson, would a Kruskal-Wallis test work in you opinion?

Comment: Normalizing is largely irrelevant (it may help you w/ interpretation, though). There may be specialized SNA analyses for this that I don't know of, but otherwise, I would try KW as suggested. @DJohnson, why not turn your comment into an official answer?

Comment: Cool, KW helps me test the null hypothesis that categories don't affect the score (my data has a p-value of 0.001 for this test, so I'm guessing categories do have something to do with the score), but doesn't predict if some categories tends to score high, while others score low. Would a  discriminant analysis help me achieve that?

Comment: If you want to test which groups differ after a significant omnibus result, you could use Dunn's test (see [various posts by @Alexis](http://stats.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=user%3a44269%20[dunn-test])). Those are good for *tests*. If the mean of your data is a meaningful measure (I think it would be despite the non-normality), you can always compute means & CIs for descriptive purposes. You could also simply make boxplots.